# Make optional alt img attribute using preg_replace

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm using this code

```
echo preg_replace('#\{{2}(.*?)\}{2}#', '<img src="/base/$1">', $input);
```

To display an input like this:

```
foo foo {{picture.jpg}} foo
```

In img html tag.
I would like to add an optional alt attribute in this format:

```
{{picture.jpg|optional}}
```

and translate into:

```
<img src="/base/$1" alt="$2">
```

only if it is present, without make another preg_replace but only improving the existing one.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
{{(.+?)(?:\|([^}]+))?}}
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/6CUKl8/2/).

---

Which in `PHP`, with the help of `preg_replace_callback()` would be:

```
<?php

$string = <<<DATA
foo foo {{picture.jpg}} foo
{{picture.jpg|optional}}
DATA;

$regex = '~{{(.+?)(?:\|([^}]+))?}}~';

$string = preg_replace_callback($regex, 
    function($match) {
        if (!empty($match[2])) {
            return "<img src='/base/{$match[1]}' alt='{$match[2]}'>";
        } else {
            return "<img src='/base/{$match[1]}'>";
        }
}, $string);

echo $string;
```

This yields

```
foo foo <img src='/base/picture.jpg'> foo
<img src='/base/picture.jpg' alt='optional'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you only forbid to use another preg_replace not another regex this works:

```
preg_replace(['#\{{2}(.*?)\|(.*?)\}{2}#', '#\{{2}(.*?)\}{2}#'], ['<img src="/base/$1" alt="$2">', '<img src="/base/$1">'], $input);
```

Working example:

```
function replacer($input) {
    return preg_replace(['#\{{2}(.*?)\|(.*?)\}{2}#', '#\{{2}(.*?)\}{2}#'], ['<img src="/base/$1" alt="$2">', '<img src="/base/$1">'], $input);
}

echo replacer('{{picture.jpg}}');
echo replacer('{{picture.jpg|optional}}');
```

Output:

```
<img src="/base/picture.jpg">
<img src="/base/picture.jpg" alt="optional">
```